# Should SE sites force reading of the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

It seems SE sites get a lot of "shopping questions", especially from new members.
Perhaps this could be remediated by disabling the editor area until the user has been seen to click on the FAQ (or a subset of it). Wouldn't it benefit everyone overall?

Comment: Try and ask a new question from a brand new account and see what it shows you

Comment: People who don't want to read the FAQ, won't.

Comment: If forced to many people will just skip it in the same way an an EULA.

Comment: If anything, we'd probably be better off with keywords in questions triggering a "potentially off-topic" warning with recommendations on where to ask instead such as `iPad` but I'm not sure how workable or friendly it would be...

Answer (score 3):

> Perhaps this could be remediated by disabling the editor area until the user has been seen to click on the FAQ (or a subset of it).

And this does what, makes them prove they can click?

Naw, if you wanna *force* them to read it, there's only one solution:

[image: Forced reading]

There is an option to force folks to click through https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask before you get to /questions/ask, but that's less about introducing the scope of the site and more about just encouraging folks to think about their question a bit (and *search* for it!) before posting it.

Comment: You only get them to *look at it* this way, not to *read it*. Perhaps direct upload to the brain, *Matrix*-style?

Comment: @DanielBeck: People also tend to *read* and still not *understand* (or wilfully ignore), so unfortunately even a direct upload to the brain might not help.